# Как поднять уровень громкости Audiomanager до максимума в андроид, а затем вернуть в исходное состояние

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста как установить максимальную громкость в android, а затем вернуть исходную громкость после выполнения метода.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно задавать громкость в `AudioManager`. Соответственно вы можете просто менять нужное вам значение.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float percent = 0.7f;
int seventyVolume = (int) (maxVolume * percent);
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seventyVolume, 0);
```